# Distinguish between string and byte array?

Tags: c, string, gcc, c99, buffer-overflow

I have a lot of functions that expect a string as argument, for which I use `char*`, but all my functions that expect a byte-array, also use `char*`.

The problem is that I can easily make the mistake of passing a byte-array in a string-function, causing all kinds of overflows, because the null-terminator cannot be found.

How is this usually delt with? I can imagine changing all my byte-array functions to take an `uint8_t`, and then the compiler will warn about signed-ness when I pass a string. Or what is the right approach here?

Comment: Make a wrapper for a byte-array??

Comment: @VaughanHilts I don't see how that solves my problem?

Comment: A string *is* a byte array.  Since you cannot actually pass arrays in C, but only a pointer to the first element, you typically also must pass a size.  Simply check if the array contains a zero value.  If it does, then it is a "string".  Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: The functions that expect null terminator won't have a length parameter. The functions that don't expect a null terminator will have a length parameter. Why don't you just call the right functions in the first place?

Comment: `uint8_t` only exists where a byte has 8 bit. `unsigned char` is probably a better choice unless you want to force your code to only compile on such hardware (which can be a valid choice)

Comment: Strings end in `NULL`, byte arrays usually don't. You could check for `NULL` in the last index of the ambiguous byte array/string.

Comment: @Joshua A couple people have shown example of wrappers below using structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is more general in C than you are thinking. Since `char*` and `char[]` are equivalent for function parameters, such a parameter may refer to three different semantic concepts:

- a pointer on one `char` object (this is the "official" definition of pointer types)
- a `char` array
- a string

In most cases where is is possible the mondern interfaces in the C standard uses `void*` for an untyped byte array, and you should probably adhere to that convention, and use `char*` only for strings.

`char[]` by themselves probably are rarely used as such; I can't imagine a lot of use cases for these. If you think of them as numbers you should use the `signed` or `unsigned` variant, if you see them just as bit pattern `unsigned char` should be your choice.

If you really mean an array as function parameter (`char` or not) you can mark that fact for the casual reader of your code by clearly indicating it:

```
void toto(size_t n, char A[const n]);
```

This is equivalent to

```
void toto(size_t n, char *const A);
```

but makes your intention clearer. And in the future there might even be tools that do the bounds checking for you.

Answer (score 2):

I generally make an array something like the following

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char* data;
   unsigned long length;
   unsigned long max_length;
} array_t;
```

then pass array_t*  around

and create array functions that take array_t*

```
void array_create( array_t* a, unsgined long length) // allocates memory, sets the max_length, zero length

void array_add(array_t* a, unsigned char byte)  // add a byte
```

etc

Comment: would probably be better to use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long`

Answer (score 0):

Write a common structure to handle both string and bytes.

```
struct str_or_byte
{
    int type;
    union
    {
        char *buf;
        char *str;
    }pointer;
    int buf_length;
}
```

If `type` is not string then access the `pointer.buf` only upto `buf_length`. Otherwise directly access `pointer.str` without checking `buf_length` and maintain it as null terminated string.

Or else maintain string also as byte array by considering only length, dont keep null terminated charater for string.

```
struct str_or_byte
{
    char *buf;
    int buf_length;
}
```

And dont use string manuplation functions which are not considering length. That means use `strncpy`, `strncat`, `strncmp` ... instead of `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strcmp`...

Answer (score 0):

C using convention.  Here's the rules I use (fashioned after the std lib)

```
void foo(char* a_string);

void bar(void* a_byte_array, size_t number_of_bytes_in_the_array);
```

This is easy to remember.  If you are passing a single char* ptr, then it MUST be a null-terminated char array.